# Get entries that have duplicate cust numbers attached to single order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all orders that have duplicate customer #'s attached.

```
 SalesNo           CustNo
  112233              56
  998877              12
  998877              33
  110044              312
```

It should return the results of:

```
 SalesNo      CustNo
 998877           12
 998877           33
```

I tried the following script but I think this will only get me orders that have duplicate entries of the exact same data.

```
select salesno, custno, COUNT(*)
from sales
GROUP BY salesno, custno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Something seems a bit off with your design if you can have a single sales number repeated in the table with different customer numbers.

Comment: Yup. Its a bug that the software vendor is working on fixing.  This is just something for us to use so we can see if it happens in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the values in the `having` clause:

```
select salesno, COUNT(*)
from sales
group by salesno
having min(custno) <> max(custno)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Did the follwoing:

```
select a.salesno, a.custno
from sales a
LEFT JOIN(
select salesno, custno
from sales
)b ON a.salesno = b.salesno
WHERE a.salesno = b.salesno AND a.custno <> b.custno
ORDER BY a.salesno
```

Comment: Sure that'll work. Consider: using INNER JOIN (or just JOIN if you're lazy like me) because you only want matches on the join condition, you can then remove the first condition of your WHERE clause because the INNER JOIN will sort that bit for you. You can also remove the subquery in the join and just straight join the table to itself and give it an alias of "b"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
select salesno, custno, COUNT(*)
from sales
GROUP BY salesno, custno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT custno) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is to use `WITH TIES` in concert with a `sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 from YourTable
 Order By sign(sum(1) over (partition by SalesNo) - 1) Desc
```

**Returns**

```
SalesNo CustNo
998877  12
998877  33
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first find the duplicate order numbers

```
select salesno
from sales
GROUP BY salesno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then search for the records of these orders

```
WITH duble AS (
    select salesno
    from sales
    GROUP BY salesno
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT s.* 
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN duble d ON s.salesno=d.salesno
```

Answer (score 0):

with cte(custno,cnt) as (
select 11235,12 union all
select 11235,14 union all
select 11236,22 union all
select 11237,33)
select * from Cte where custno in(select custno from cte group by custno having COUNT(*) > 1)